# Hide Azure VM behind proxy with Azure AD authentication

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-virtual-machine

We have an authoring instance of our CMS hosted on an Azure VM. The authoring system's web front end (even the login page) should only be accessable for users that have been authenticated against our Azure AD. Browsing the Azure documentation, I found out about Azure AD Application Proxy, but unfortunately it only seems to work for on-premises applications. Is there something like Azure AD Application Proxy for applications hosted in Azure?
Thank you for your help!

Best,

Fabian

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try **Active Directory Federation Services**. It provides simplified, secured identity federation and Web single sign-on (SSO) capabilities.

> Federation with Azure AD or O365 enables users to authenticate using on-premises credentials and access all resources in cloud.  As a result, it becomes important to have a highly available AD FS infrastructure to ensure access to resources both on-premises and in the cloud.

There are several steps to deploy AD FS in Azure:

1. Deploying the network
2. Create storage accounts
3. Create availability sets
4. Deploy virtual machines
5. Configuring the domain controller / AD FS servers
6. Deploying Internal Load Balancer (ILB)
7. Configuring the Web Application Proxy server
8. Deploying the Internet Facing (Public) Load Balancer
9. Securing the network
10. Test the AD FS sign-in

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnect-azure-adfs).